# DateTimeFormatter with fixed nano value length

Tags: java, formatting

I cannot find a predefined `DateTimeFormatter` that prints the nano second section with the same number of digits every time. The closets I get is `ISO_LOCAL_TIME`:

`LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)` generates values such as:

```
14:45:42.0496733
14:45:43.4205
14:45:45.6078279
14:45:45.623833
```

`.4205` actually means nano second `.4205000` (or, more correctly, `.420500000`) but zeros at the end are omitted. I would like a predefined `DateTimeFormatter` that prints the nano second section with the same width every time since the "missing" zeros mess up my tabbed log files. So I'm looking for this:

```
14:45:42.0496733
14:45:43.4205000
14:45:45.6078279
14:45:45.6238330
```

Or this:

```
14:45:42.049673300
14:45:43.420500000
14:45:45.607827900
14:45:45.623833000
```

I understand that I can use `String.format` to add trailing zeros, or that I can create my own `DateTimeFormatter` using `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 7, 7, true)`... but I would prefer to using something out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own pattern in a `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(String pattern)` like this:

**Using *nano-of-seconds* (`n`):**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter nineNanosDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnnnn");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println(now.format(nineNanosDtf));
}
```

which outputs 9 nano-of-seconds: `19:44:28.791000000`

**or *fraction-of-seconds* (`S`):**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter nineNanosDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println(now.format(nineNanosDtf));
}
```

I chose a fix amount of 9 fractions-of-seconds in this case by `SSSSSSSSS` which will be filled up with zeros if there aren't other nano values to be printed.

which outputs `19:43:49.592000000`

## EDIT

I tried the pattern with a single `n` as well as with 8, 9 and 10 `n`s several times, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // two date time Strings
    String datetimeOne = "19:08:58.012345678"; // one with a leading zero nano
    String datetimeTwo = "19:08:58.123456789"; // and one without

    // several patterns that might be interesting
    DateTimeFormatter singleNPatternDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.n");
    DateTimeFormatter eightNsPatternDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnnn");
    DateTimeFormatter nineNsPatternDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnnnn");
    DateTimeFormatter tenNsPatternDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnnnnn");

    // parse the two Strings
    LocalTime localTimeOne = LocalTime.parse(datetimeOne, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME);
    LocalTime localTimeTwo = LocalTime.parse(datetimeOne, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME);

    // print / format both and LocalTime.now() with the single 'n' pattern
    System.out.println("1 * n:\t" + localTimeOne.format(singleNPatternDtf) + "\t—\t"
            + localTimeTwo.format(singleNPatternDtf) + "\t—\t" 
            + LocalTime.now().format(singleNPatternDtf));
    // print / format both and LocalTime.now() with eight 'n's pattern
    System.out.println("8 * n:\t" + localTimeOne.format(eightNsPatternDtf) + "\t—\t"
            + localTimeTwo.format(eightNsPatternDtf) + "\t—\t" 
            + LocalTime.now().format(eightNsPatternDtf));
    // print / format both and LocalTime.now() with nine 'n's pattern
    System.out.println("9 * n:\t" + localTimeOne.format(nineNsPatternDtf) + "\t—\t"
            + localTimeTwo.format(nineNsPatternDtf) + "\t—\t" 
            + LocalTime.now().format(nineNsPatternDtf));
    // print / format both and LocalTime.now() with ten 'n's pattern
    System.out.println("10 * n:\t" + localTimeOne.format(tenNsPatternDtf) + "\t—\t"
            + localTimeTwo.format(tenNsPatternDtf) + "\t—\t" 
            + LocalTime.now().format(tenNsPatternDtf));
}
```

The code produced output like the following (in most cases):

```
1 * n:  19:08:58.12345678   —   19:08:58.12345678   —   19:26:40.23000000
8 * n:  19:08:58.12345678   —   19:08:58.12345678   —   19:26:40.26000000
9 * n:  19:08:58.012345678  —   19:08:58.012345678  —   19:26:40.026000000
10 * n: 19:08:58.0012345678 —   19:08:58.0012345678 —   19:26:40.0026000000
```

That means a significant difference in the return value depending on the pattern provided to the `DateTimeFormatter` used...

Unfortunately, the pattern with 8 `n`s wasn't really working every time.
Instead, it sometimes threw an `Exception`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException:
Field NanoOfSecond cannot be printed as the value 155000000 exceeds the maximum print width of 8
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$NumberPrinterParser.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.format(Unknown Source)
```

which points to an invalid pattern, so the one with eight 'n's cannot be recommended.

Decide yourself which one to use, a comment points to the one with nine `n`s.

I would (now) prefer it over the single or ten 'n's.

Comment: Do you think S is better than n. Is fraction of second better than nano of second?

Comment: @mwarren Not really, depends on the requirements, I think.

Comment: @mwarren For my part I prefer uppercase `S` over `n`. For one thing it’s flexible, works correctly for 7, 8 or 9 decimals (where `n` only works for 9). I think that `n` is more for situations where you want to print the nanoseconds separately from the seconds and/or not as a fraction of those.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough analysis! Obviously one must be careful here. I will use SSSSSSSSS (but first I need to test some corner cases).

Comment: @Stefan you're welcome, it made me curious and my first answer was roughly flawed so I just had to dig into it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For 7 digits and "out of the box" this is possible:

```
DateTimeFormatter test1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS");
```

For 9-10 digits (and out of the box) this is a solution:

```
DateTimeFormatter test2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnnnnn");
```

(With less than 9 nano digits, you will end up in `java.time.DateTimeException: Field NanoOfSecond cannot be printed...`)

---

Usage:

```
//for(int i =0;i<100;i++) ...
LocalDateTime t1 = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(t1.format(test1));
System.out.println(t1.format(test2));
```

...unfortunately, I failed to test any timestamps with "lowest nanos > 0":

```
16:05:23.124 // <- ISO_LOCAL_TIME
16:05:23.1240000 //<- test1
16:05:23.1240000000 //<- test2
```